# Should there be one instance of flutter_adaptive_scaffold that displays all pages or an instance per page?

Tags: flutter

We are looking to use AdaptiveScaffold from the flutter_adaptive_scaffold package to achieve a traditional navigation drawer/body layout but the team is not sure on how best to implement it.

Should there be one instance of AdaptiveScaffold that acts as a parent container for all other screens or should we create separate implementations of AdaptiveScaffold for each screen.

## Option 1

- MainScaffold
- HomePage
- Settings
- Payments

## Option 2

- HomePage
- HomePageScaffold
- Settings
- SettingsScaffold
- Payments
- PaymentsScaffold

What was the intended usage pattern by the Flutter team? Again we don't have complex requirements just looking to implement traditional nav drawer experience. Thanks!